# MySQL Return Column Name And Count

Tags: mysql

This is a sample of my table:

```
Column1 | Column2 | Column3
================================
Data1   | 2Data  | 3Data
Data1   | 2data2 | 3data2
Data1   | 2data3 | 3data3
Data1   | 2data4 | 3data4
Data2   | 2data5 | 3data5
Data2   | 2data6 | 3data6
Data2   | 2data7 | 3data7
```

---

The result I want is,

```
Column1 | Count
===============
Data1   | 4
Data2   | 3
```

Is this possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Review the [aggregate functions](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html). This is a rudimentary `COUNT()` with `GROUP BY Column1`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT Column1, COUNT(*)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Column1
```